# How do I center this div on the screen? The positioning seems to be off by a little bit

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #7a64fa;
    }
    
    .container {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-top: -50px;
      margin-left: -100px;
      padding-top: 75px;
      padding-right: 50px;
      padding-bottom: 75px;
      padding-left: 50px;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }
    
    label {
      font-size: 25px;
      font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", monospace;
    }
    
    input {
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    
    .ftm {
      display: inline-block;
    }
  </style>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Feet to Meter</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="ftm">
      <label>Feet</label><br /> <input style="height: 40px;" type="number" name="feet">
    </div>
    <div class="ftm">
      <label>Meter</label> <br /> <input style="height: 40px;" type="number" name="meter">
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I was looking to see why the container DIV wont fully center on the screen. I have tried to adjust the css for the container but cant seem to get the div to stay in the center. It might have something to do with the padding as well.

[image: pic]

Comment: Flex-box will be best and easy shot for you but you can use translate property too to center

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to center the `div` using

```
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -100px;
```

This doesn't work because the div doesn't have dimensions 100x200. Use relative transform instead:

```
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the `.container` class remove, the margins

```
margin-top: -50px; // remove
margin-left: -100px;  // remove
```

Add

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Answer (score 0):

remove margin-left from `.container` and add `transform: translateX(-50%);`
Visit [translate() by mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate()) to know more about css translate

```
      .container {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    margin-top: -50px;
    /* margin-left: -100px; */
    padding-top: 75px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 75px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
```